# Store DBT run execution output for auditing / analytics

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, dbt

I'd like to know if I can store the outuput of a DBT run (successes or failures, model name, execution time, maybe some "execution ID" into a table, so that I can do analytics of the successes / errors.

```
19:15:19  1 of 3 START table model dataset.table_1 ......... [RUN] 
19:15:19  1 of 3 ERROR table model dataset.table_1 ......... [ERROR in 999s]
19:15:20  2 of 3 SKIP relation dataset.table................ [SKIP]
19:15:20  3 of 3 start table dataset.table_3................ [RUN]
19:15:20  3 of 3 OK created dataset.table_3................. [CREATE TABLE (1M rows, 10TB processed)]
```

Is there a way I can get this info tabulated? Maybe is there some package that does it?

```
model_name      | started_at | finished_at | status
-----------------------------------------------------
dataset.table_3 | 19:15:20   | 19:15:20    | success
-----------------------------------------------------
dataset.table_2 | 19:15:19   | NULL        | skip
-----------------------------------------------------
dataset.table_1 | 19:15:19   | 19:15:19    | error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best way to do this is to use the Brooklyn Data's excellent [dbt-artifacts](https://hub.getdbt.com/brooklyn-data/dbt_artifacts/latest/) package. You will specifically be interested in the [`fct_dbt__model_executions`](https://brooklyn-data.github.io/dbt_artifacts/#!/model/model.dbt_artifacts.fct_dbt__model_executions) table that it produces.

When dbt runs, it logs structured data to `run_results.json` and `manifest.json` files. This packages reads those files and then inserts data into your data warehouse based on their contents. This is much faster and better than adding model hooks that `insert` the data directly, at the end of each model execution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're describing the elementary data reliability DBT package.
from the official docs: https://hub.getdbt.com/elementary-data/elementary/latest/

The package automatically uploads the dbt artifacts and run results to tables in your data warehouse:

Run results tables:

- dbt_run_results
- model_run_results
- snapshot_run_results
- elementary_test_results (all dbt test results)

Metadata tables:

- dbt_models
- dbt_tests
- dbt_sources
- dbt_exposures
- dbt_metrics
- dbt_snapshots